# This makes eleven rebuses

Tags: rebus

Creating rebuses can make a person feel this way.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love answering these!

> Exuberant

So,

> X+uber+ant

Comment: Glad you enjoy them (maybe solving them causes you to be exuberant, too. =D).